# Good book on Spherical Trigonometry

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, spherical-trigonometry

Possible approach/content:

- Modern
- Practical (Navigation/Geodesy)
- unifies with Euclidean/Hyperbolic Trigonometry

Comment: The best Wikipedia seems to have is this: http://www.gutenberg.org/files/19770/19770-pdf.pdf?session_id=6bd3be9532633032431f9f88dbe02b16daeafb1f although it is extremely old. I remember spherical trigonometry being an "extra" section in a textbook I had from high school way back when, but I don't even remember what that book was called, much less the author. I will try to post it if I remember, but I probably won't.

Comment: This one is also ancient -- http://www.wilbourhall.org/pdfs/spherical_trigonometry2.pdf. I agree that it is surprising that there are not more good references.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_geometry

Comment: I finally found the book I was thinking about. Chapter 10 of "Trigonometry with Applications" by Graham, Sorgenfrey is all about Spherical Trigonometry. https://www.amazon.com/Trigonometry-Applications-John-Graham/dp/0395304504 The treatment might be too basic, I'm not sure what you're looking for. Before I learned about elliptic geometry I always told myself I would get around to reading that chapter and doing its exercises one day -- now maybe I'll just read something on elliptic geometry instead. Anyway the used copies on Amazon are cheap, the new ones not so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know exactly if this is what you are looking for or if it's at the right level, but you might want to have a look at the first three chapters of John Ratcliffe's [*Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387331972). They concern Euclidean, spherical and hyperbolic geometry (with sections about trigonometry), and the book is modern and (in my opinion) well-writen.

Answer (score 1):

Try Lyman Kells.  Cheap used editions available.  I have the War Department paperback.

[https://www.amazon.com/spherical-trigonometry-tables-Department-education/dp/B0007I8VA6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007I8VA6)